# Solving the 1D Schrödinger equation under the potential $V(x) = f(t)x$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Following the sketch given in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17768/), I hoped to solve the 1+1 dimensional Schrodinger equation under a potential $f(t)x$ by using a time dependent boost.

$$\left(\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + f(t)x \right) \Psi(x,t) = i\hbar \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$$

When I attempt to apply a boost in the form

$$
\Psi(x,t) = e^{-i\frac{F(t)}{\hbar} x} \tilde{\Psi}(x,t)
$$

where $F(t)$ is the antiderivative of $f(t)$, I get

$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{\partial^2 \tilde{\Psi}}{\partial x^2} - 2i \frac{F(t)}{\hbar}\frac{\partial \tilde{\Psi}}{\partial x}  -\frac{F(t)^2}{\hbar^2} \tilde \Psi^2\right) = i\hbar \frac{\partial \tilde \Psi}{\partial t}
$$

but I am unsure of how to proceed. If I attempt to find a separable solution in the form $\tilde \Psi(x,t) = X(x) \Phi (t)$, I cannot resolve the cross term.

$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{\ddot X}{X} - 2i \frac{F(t)}{\hbar}\frac{\dot X}{X} \right) = i\hbar \frac{\dot \Phi}{\Phi} - \frac{F(t)^2}{2m} 
$$

Did I choose the wrong ansatz for a boost? Or, is my derivation mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You took the right boost. In order to simplify the resulting equation further, we need a change of variable, namely $z := x + \alpha(t)$, sucht that $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \dot{\alpha}(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ by the chain rule. In consequence, your Schrödinger equation takes the following form :
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial\tilde{\Psi}}{\partial t} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\tilde{\Psi}}{\partial z^2} + i\hbar\left(\frac{F(t)}{m}-
\dot{\alpha}(t)\right)\frac{\partial\tilde{\Psi}}{\partial z} + \frac{F(t)^2}{2m}\tilde{\Psi}
$$
Choosing $\alpha(t) := \frac{1}{m}\int F(t)\mathrm{d}t$, we get
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial\tilde{\Psi}}{\partial t} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\tilde{\Psi}}{\partial z^2} + \frac{F(t)^2}{2m}\tilde{\Psi},
$$
which can now be solved in several ways (see e.g. [here](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.64.034101)). For example, taking the Fourier transform with respect to the variable $z$, we end with
$$
\tilde{\Psi}(k,t) = \tilde{\Psi}_0(k)\exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\left(\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}t+\int_0^t\frac{F(t)^2}{2m}\mathrm{d}t\right)\right)
$$
where $\tilde{\Psi}_0(k)$ is an initial condition. Finally, it is to be noticed that, even if the final result will obviously depend on the initial condition, linear potential tend to produce solutions involving Airy functions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am just posting another question where I am asking for solution verification of my work in momentum space. When I finish it in around 5 minutes would it be too much for me to ask for your reviewal?

Comment: My attempt is available at this link. The final answers appear similar. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/746519/

Comment: @Talmsmen Sure ;)