# Momentum Space Solutions of the 1D Schrodinger equation in the Potential $f(t)x$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform

Yesterday, I asked a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/746378/) about solving the 1D Schrodinger equation in a time varying potential $f(t)x$ using a method solely in configuration space. Although this approach does not directly answer my original question — hence my asking it separately, I would be greatly appreciative if someone could verify my solution.

$$
\left(\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + f(t)x\right) \Psi(x,t) = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(x,t)
$$

Then, I used the cosmetic exchanges $x\mapsto i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial p}$ and $-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \mapsto p$ to produce the equation

$$
\left(\frac{p^2}{2m} + i\hbar f(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial p}\right) \Psi(x,t) = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(x,t)
$$

Then, changing coordinates corresponds to a time-dependent boost in momentum space where $F(t)$ is antiderivative of $f(t)$

$$
\begin{align}
p' &= p + F(t) \\
t' &= t
\end{align}
$$

producing the relationships

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial p} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial p'}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t'} + f(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial p} 
\end{align}
$$

and yielding the final equation

$$
-\frac{(p' - F(t))^2}{2m} \hat\Psi(p', t') = i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t'} \hat\Psi(p', t')
$$

The solution then becomes

$$
\hat \Psi(p', t') = C \exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar} \int_0^{t'} \frac{(p' - F(\tau))^2}{2m} d\tau\right)
$$

or removing the primes by relabeling

$$\hat \Psi(p, t) = C \exp\left(-\frac{i}{\hbar} \int_0^{t} \frac{(p - F(\tau))^2}{2m} d\tau\right)$$

Comment: Hi again @Talmsmen ! Seems correct to me, apart from the typo in $p'$, which should be $p' = p +  F(t)$, hence $\partial_t = \partial_{t'} + f(t)\partial_p$, I guess. But the final answers are not impacted.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll get rid of that extra $x$.